# SQLDataStore with output parameters, getting ParameterName not contained in this SqlParameterCollection error

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

The ultimate goal of what I am trying to accomplish is this: 
Button at the bottom of a material order form Inserts a new record in the material order table with the ProjectID and current date. After the record is inserted, redirect the page to the new order id so it can be modified.

If I take out the OnInserted method that is supposed to grab the SCOPE_IDENTITY() output of the insert, the record inserts fine, but with the call, I keep getting "SQLParameter with ParameterName 'NewOrderID' is not contained by this SqlParameterCollection"

ASPX Formview

```
<asp:FormView ID="FvFooter" runat="server" DataKeyNames="OrderID" 
    DataSourceID="FvMatOrdersSQL" ForeColor="#333333" OnItemCommand="FvFooter_OnItemCommand">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <br/>
        <b>Notes</b>
        <br/>
        <asp:Label ID="TxtNotes" runat="server" BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="1" 
        Text='<%# Eval("Notes").ToString().Replace(Environment.NewLine, "<br />") %>'/>
        <br/>
        <asp:LinkButton ID="LbEditNotes" runat="server" CssClass="NoPrint" 
            CausesValidation="False" CommandName="Edit" Text="Edit"/>
        <br/>
        <br/>
        <asp:Button ID="DeleteButton" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" 
            CssClass="NoPrint" CommandName="DeleteOrder" Text="Delete"/>
        &nbsp;<asp:Button ID="NewButton" runat="server" CausesValidation="True" 
            CssClass="NoPrint" CommandName="NewOrder" Text="New Order"/>
        &nbsp;<asp:Button ID="EmailButton" runat="server" CausesValidation="True" 
            CssClass="NoPrint" CommandName="Email" Text="Email"/>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:FormView>
```

SQL DataSource

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="FvMatOrdersSQL" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ProjectLogicTestConnectionString %>"
    SelectCommand="SELECT mo.OrderID, mo.ProjectID, p.ProjectName, mo.OrderedByEmpID, emp.Name, 
        mo.OrderDate, mo.DateNeeded, mo.ReasonID, mor.Description, mo.Notes 
            FROM tblMatOrder AS mo 
            LEFT OUTER JOIN tblMatOrderReason AS mor ON mo.ReasonID = mor.ReasonID 
            INNER JOIN tblProject AS p ON mo.ProjectID = p.ProjectID 
            LEFT OUTER JOIN tblEmployee AS emp ON mo.OrderedByEmpID = emp.EmployeeID
            WHERE mo.OrderID = @OrderID"
DeleteCommand="DELETE FROM tblMatOrder WHERE OrderID = @OrderID"
InsertCommand="INSERT INTO tblMatOrder (OrderDate, ProjectID) VALUES (@OrderDate, @ProjectID); 
    SELECT @NewOrderID = SCOPE_IDENTITY()"
UpdateCommand="UPDATE tblMatOrder SET OrderDate = @OrderDate, OrderedByEmpID = @OrderedByEmpID, 
 DateNeeded = @DateNeeded, ReasonID = @ReasonID, Notes = @Notes
 WHERE OrderID = @OrderID"
 OnInserted="FvMatOrdersSQL_OnInserted">
    <SelectParameters>
        <asp:RouteParameter Name="OrderID" Type="Int32" RouteKey="OrderID"/>
    </SelectParameters>
    <DeleteParameters>
        <asp:Parameter Name="OrderID" Type="Int32" DefaultValue="0"/>
    </DeleteParameters>
    <InsertParameters>
        <asp:Parameter Name="OrderDate" Type="DateTime"/>
        <asp:Parameter Name="ProjectID" Type="Int32"/>
        <asp:Parameter Direction ="Output" Name="NewOrderID" Type="Int32" DefaultValue="0"/>
    </InsertParameters>
    <UpdateParameters>
        <asp:RouteParameter Name="OrderID" Type="Int32" RouteKey="OrderID"/>
        <asp:Parameter Name="OrderDate" Type="DateTime"/>
        <asp:Parameter Name="OrderedByEmpID" Type="Int32"/>
        <asp:Parameter Name="DateNeeded" Type="DateTime"/>
        <asp:Parameter Name="ReasonID" Type="Int32"/>
        <asp:Parameter Name="Notes" Type="String"/>
    </UpdateParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

On Button Click codebehind

```
protected void FvFooter_OnItemCommand(object sender, FormViewCommandEventArgs e)
        {
            switch (e.CommandName)
            {
                case "DeleteOrder":
                    // Confirmation stuff here
                    break;
                case "NewOrder" when Page.IsValid:
                    Label lblProjectId = (Label)FvHeader.FindControl("LblProjectID");
                    String strOrderDate = DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString();
                    FvMatOrdersSQL.InsertParameters.Clear();
                    FvMatOrdersSQL.InsertParameters.Add("ProjectID", lblProjectId.Text);
                    FvMatOrdersSQL.InsertParameters.Add("OrderDate", strOrderDate);
                    FvMatOrdersSQL.Insert();
                    break;
                case "Email" when Page.IsValid:

                    break;
            }
        }
```

OnInserted codebehind

```
protected void FvMatOrdersSQL_OnInserted(object sender, SqlDataSourceStatusEventArgs e)
        {
            String strOrderId = e.Command.Parameters["@NewOrderID"].Value.ToString();
            Response.Redirect("MatOrderDetails.aspx?OrderID=" + strOrderId);
        }
```

I've tried to base as much of my code on the example here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228051.aspx but apparently I'm missing something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've put yr code and have created a db close to yr select to figure out yr problem, I have to admit it wasn't easy :) please

change this

```
 FvMatOrdersSQL.InsertParameters.Clear();
 FvMatOrdersSQL.InsertParameters.Add("ProjectID", lblProjectId.Text);
 FvMatOrdersSQL.InsertParameters.Add("OrderDate", strOrderDate);
```

To:

```
FvMatOrdersSQL.InsertParameters["ProjectID"].DefaultValue = lblProjectId.Text;
FvMatOrdersSQL.InsertParameters["OrderDate"].DefaultValue = strOrderDate;
```

Don't remove the params which you've already created in the UI!

Comment: I think I see what was going on. If I had to guess, the `InsertParameters.Clear()` was in effect taking out the output parameter. With the changes you listed, I got an error that the input string was not in the correct format, but that was a problem with my `Response.Redirect()` which I got figured out.